# Interpreting descriptions of sets

Tags: strength-training, sets

Many strength training programs describe sets something like this:

3 sets 8-10 reps, 10-12 reps, 13-15 reps

I'm not sure what this actually means.
Does it mean, 8-10, 8-10, 8-10 (drop the weight here) then 10-12, 10-12, 10-12 (drop the weight again) 13-15, 13-15, 13-15?

Or does it mean 8-10, 10-12, 13-15 (drop the weight here); 8-10, 10-12, 13-15 (drop the weight again); 8-10, 10-12-13-15

Or does it mean something completely different?

UPDATE:

To clarify, what I want to know is this:
Do you do three of the first range, three of the second range, three of the third range *OR* Do you do three of all three ranges, three of all three ranges, three of all three ranges? (In both scenarios a total of 9 sets will occur)

Comment: Since this is answered, I'll leave a comment - that means, to me, one set with reps in the first range, one set with reps in the second range, one set with reps in the third range.  You adjust weight as necessary so you are able to do the number of reps within the range of the sets, hopefully just barely.  So, for my imaginary bench press workout, first set with 145 lbs, 13 - 15 reps; second set, 155 lbs 10-12 reps; third set is 165 lbs, 8-10 reps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would do 3 of the lower range at a heavier rep range, then progress rep range upwards lowering the weight of muscle exhaustion is the goal. Alternatively, depending on the hardness or the training you could also go 1 8-10 heavy, lighten load go to the next rep range, lighten load go to the next rep range with pauses and that would be the set. The second example would be a lot harder

Comment: Ah, I should mention that I'm not really asking about the ranges themselves, they were just chosen arbitrarily and dropping the weight/increasing it is something that I saw was a common factor among programs. What I'm actually asking is what is the order in which they're done. If you look back at the question, you can see that what I'm trying to find out is if you do: `three of all ranges`, `three of all ranges`, `three of all ranges` OR `three of first range`, `three of second range`, `three of third`.

Comment: Unless your a professional body builder or aspiring to be one. That means do one of each set. If you're an aspiring professional that would mean do 9 sets of three each

Comment: Okay, then let's assume someone is an aspiring body-builder: what are the orders of the ranges executed? That's the question I'm asking.

Comment: You would do 3 of the lower range at a heavier rep range, then progress rep range upwards lowering the weight of muscle exhaustion is the goal. Alternatively, depending on the hardness or the training you could also go 1 8-10 heavy, lighten load go to the next rep range, lighten load go to the next rep range with pauses and that would be the set. The second example would be a lot harder

Comment: If you update your answer with that explanation (as it is what I was looking for) I'll accept your answer

Comment: Okay sorry for the confusion changed it :)

Comment: No worries, it was good information to have just not what I needed. Thank you!